# Pandas. Why is it splitting up df into multiple rows when I do groupby and agg count?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the below, that is looping through and reading 3 csv files that are about 120MB each with the same columns. I'm doing a group by and counting the impression_id, then combining the df's into a final df.

But for some reason the below, is splitting out my rows, but if I total the IMP_ID_COUNT rows its the correct amount, but why is it splitting it into another row and not just showing in 1 row?

```
df_list = []

for filepath in keys:

    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\t', skiprows=1, header=None)

    # checking if file has 19 columns.
    if df.shape[1] == 19:
        df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[2:5, 6]].copy()

        df.columns = ['normalized_page_url', 'impression_id', 'ts', 'user_ip_country']
        df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts']).dt.date

        df_agg = df.groupby(['normalized_page_url', 'ts', 'user_ip_country'], as_index=False).agg(
            imp_id_count=('impression_id', 'count'))

        df_list.append(df_agg)

    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Number of columns in file are {df.shape[1]} should be 19...')
df_final = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
```

This is what the files have (I'm showing for 1 normalized_page_url):

| NORMALIZED_PAGE_URL | IMPRESSION_ID | TS | USER_IP_COUNTRY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| en/best-skincare-products | 04D1889E731CD4 | 2022-01-23 21:41:25.000 | gb |
| en/best-skincare-products | FD53D54AA8512 | 2022-01-23 04:12:25.000 | gb |
| en/best-skincare-products | 925B1167CDSK1 | 2022-01-23 06:03:01.000 | gb |

and in the final dataframe I see (I've added the final file name and row number to show more clearly):

| FINAL_FILENAME | FILE_ROW_NUMBER | NORMALIZED_PAGE_URL | TS | USER_IP_COUNTRY | IMP_ID_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date=2022-01-23/2022-01-23.csv | 148 | en/best-skincare-products | 2022-01-23 | gb | 2 |
| date=2022-01-23/2022-01-23.csv | 121207 | en/best-skincare-products | 2022-01-23 | gb | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without some sample data, but I can see only 2 possibilities:

**1. Grouping variables *looks* the same, but they aren't**

If the combination `('NORMALIZED_PAGE_URL', 'TS', 'USER_IP_COUNTRY')` is unique for each file, that's the only possible explanation.

- Are you sure, that both `NORMALIZED_PAGE_URL` and  `USER_IP_COUNTRY` don't have any trailing whitespaces?

You can check this by doing fe.:

```py
df['user_ip_country'].value_counts()
```

EDIT: Another way of checking this would be comparing rows:

```py
df_final.iloc[0, :-1] == df_final.iloc[1, :-1]
```

Where the `0` and `1` are the row numbers of "final datasets" that were splitted, fe:

```py
from io import StringIO
csv = """en/best-skincare-products  04D1889E731CD4  2022-01-23 21:41:25.000 gb
en/best-skincare-products   FD53D54AA8512   2022-01-23 04:12:25.000 gb
en/best-skincare-products   925B1167CDSK1   2022-01-23 06:03:01.000 gb """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep='\t', header=None)
df.columns = ['normalized_page_url', 'impression_id', 'ts', 'user_ip_country']
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts']).dt.date
df_final = df.groupby(['normalized_page_url', 'ts', 'user_ip_country'], as_index=False).agg(
            imp_id_count=('impression_id', 'count'))

#   normalized_page_url         ts          user_ip_country imp_id_count
#0  en/best-skincare-products   2022-01-23  gb              2
#1  en/best-skincare-products   2022-01-23  gb              1
```

As you can see in that case, output looks just like in your example - rows `0` and `1` looks exactly the same, but if you compare the rows, you'll see in which column there is a difference:

```
df_final.iloc[0, :-1] == df_final.iloc[1, :-1]

#normalized_page_url     True
#ts                      True
#user_ip_country        False
```

If that's the case, you could use `.str.strip()` before doing the groupby:

```
df['user_ip_country'] = df['user_ip_country'].str.strip()
df_final = df.groupby(['normalized_page_url', 'ts', 'user_ip_country'], as_index=False).agg(
            imp_id_count=('impression_id', 'count'))

#   normalized_page_url         ts          user_ip_country imp_id_count
#0  en/best-skincare-products   2022-01-23  gb              3
```

**2. The combination** `('NORMALIZED_PAGE_URL', 'TS', 'USER_IP_COUNTRY')` **occurs in multiple iterations of for loop**

You are appending the results, so if given combination occurs in multiple files, for each file it would have a different results. If that's the case, this:

```py
df_all = pd.DataFrame()

for filepath in keys:
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\t', skiprows=1, header=None)
    
    if df.shape[1] == 19:
        df = df.iloc[:, [2, 3, 4, 6]].copy()
        df.columns = ['normalized_page_url', 'impression_id', 'ts', 'user_ip_country']
        df_all = df_all.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Number of columns in file are {df.shape[1]} should be 19...')

df_all['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df_all['ts']).dt.date  
df_agg = df_all.groupby(['normalized_page_url', 'ts', 'user_ip_country'], as_index=False).agg(
            imp_id_count=('impression_id', 'count'))
```

should help you (it appends all of the datasets and does the groupby on whole dataset).

Comment: I've added some sample data.
For your 1st answer, I'm confused I'm not sure what value_count on user_ip_country show me? I have many rows with the the same user_ip_country so for us it shows 9,321 for gb it shows 2,321, etc.
 I tried you're second answer, but the df_all is coming up empty once the loop finishes running.

Comment: Regarding 1st part of the answer - you can print out the unique values from columns `user_ip_country` and `normalized_page_url`, for example with `.value_counts()` just to check if there are "the same" url's  or countries multiple times (fe. `"gb"` and `"gb "`). If that's the case you have to fix this column by using `.str.strip()`

Comment: Regarding 2nd part of the answer - my bad, I made a mistake and didn't assign result of the `df_all.append()`. I edited the answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!